# Return refcursor after select for update

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to return the data through refcursor that is used in Select for update but I am not able to find any way. Can any one please guide me.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SELECT_SCHEDULED_REPORTS
        (o_scheduledreports_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)

    IS
      CURSOR report_ids
  IS
    SELECT *
    FROM dwp_rep_scheduler_t
    WHERE SCHEDULE_ID IN
      (SELECT SCHEDULE_ID
      FROM
        (SELECT *
        FROM dwp_rep_scheduler_t a
        WHERE status      = 1
        AND schedule_type = 1
        ORDER BY a.start_date
        )
    WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
      ) FOR UPDATE OF status;

    BEGIN         
     FOR report_id IN report_ids
      LOOP
       UPDATE dwp_rep_scheduler_t SET status = 2 WHERE CURRENT OF report_ids;
      END LOOP;
        COMMIT;

-- can I do something like open o_scheduledreports_cursor for report_ids

      END;
    /
```

As suggested by @Lalit Kumar B, i tried following but now it compiles with error as "PLS-00221: 'O_SCHEDULEDREPORTS_CURSOR' is not a procedure or is undefined"

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SELECT_SCHEDULED_REPORTS (
   o_scheduledreports_cursor OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
begin
  open o_scheduledreports_cursor  for
          SELECT *
            FROM dwp_rep_scheduler_t
           WHERE SCHEDULE_ID IN (SELECT SCHEDULE_ID
                                   FROM (  SELECT *
                                             FROM dwp_rep_scheduler_t a
                                            WHERE status = 1 AND schedule_type = 1
                                         ORDER BY a.start_date)
                                  WHERE ROWNUM <= 5)
      FOR UPDATE OF status;

   BEGIN
      FOR report_id IN o_scheduledreports_cursor
      LOOP
         UPDATE dwp_rep_scheduler_t
            SET status = 2
          WHERE CURRENT OF report_ids;
      END LOOP;
      COMMIT;
   END;
END SELECT_SCHEDULED_REPORTS;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

`Select for update` is a programming tool which you would use to ensure that no one else updates your data. Inside you `PL/SQL`, you would use the `rows locked for update`, and then do the required transaction. `Commit` your changes, Oracle would release the `lock mode 3`.

You could simply do,

```
Open cur for
 select column_list from table where ....
```

Not that specific, but, this asktom link about `select for ...update` is a good read https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:927629362932

You might also be interested to know few interesting things about the clause, here is my take on a myth about `select..for update` http://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2014/09/04/a-myth-about-row-exclusive-table-lock-on-select-for-update-with-no-rows/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Lalit, i tried what u suggested but now its compiling with error. Can you suggest what went wrong. Have updated the post.

Comment: No, that is not what I suggested. Use for update clause for the transaction inside the pl/sql code. Open cursor for the select statement only, no update for clause here. And, please compile your code in `SQL*Plus` and use `SHOW ERROR` to see the `error stack`. Copy paste the entire thing.

Comment: I dont understand, if I will not lock the data selected by curser then how can we en-shore that same data is not being used before this instance updates it. I am not a regular DB guy so my understanding is a little less...